# Can Random Forests deal with variables that affect each other (and respect their temporal sequence)?

Tags: time-series, random-forest

I'm studying temporal aspects of a decision-related brain process. For this study I want to see how much the information (absolute amount of contrast and/or amplitude) of a stimulus at different time points affects the final decision. In a Random Forest I made in MATLAB R2019a, the absolute value of the stimulus is a single variable for each time point (80*50ms, so 80 variables) as we want to see what time points are important for the decision.

However, the absolute value of a stimulus at one time point can affect the role of the stimulus at the following time point. Imagine two situations where the stimulus at time point N has an (arbitrary) absolute value of 5:

*If the stimulus at time point N-1 has a value of 0, a value of 5 is relatively high and might play a bigger role in the decisionmaking*

*If the stimulus at time point N-1 has a value of 10, a value of 5 is relatively low and might play a lesser role in the decisionmaking*

My question comes down to this: is it possible to design a Random Forest that takes the sequence of the variables into account, in a sort of hierarchical fashion with the first variable (time point) influencing the second variable (time point), but not the other way around? If so, what tools are available to ensure the Forest is 'aware' of this specific dependancy between variables? Any literature or alternative techniques for this problem are also highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. If you must use a random forest, you could consider creating new variables that take into account the dependency on previous time points.

Comment: The generic random forest doesn't account for temporal or other dependencies. If you care about this kind of data, you'll either have to make new features per @mkt's suggestion or use a model that *does* respect temporal dependencies. (Or maybe someone's invented a time-series random forest, but I haven't encountered such a beast.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning the comments above into an answer.

I don't think it's possible to build in such time-dependence into a random forest. If you must use one, you could create new variables that take into account the dependence on previous time points. Or as @Sycorax points out, you could use a modelling approach that explicitly accounts for time-dependence.